# Computed height different from specified height

Tags: css

While making a button on my website, I was trying to draw inspiration from the search button at www.google.com.

So, using google chrome as the browser, I went to www.google.com, right clicked on the "Google Search" button and selected "Inspect Element" option. I saw that the button element has the class "lsb" and css specifies a height of 30px for an element of this class. This specification has not been overridden by another statement (or else chrome would tell me so). Still, when I look at the computed value, I see that the height is 43px, rather than 30px.

So, I am wondering, what is causing this increase in the height of the element?

Comment: There is a "Computed Style" section for any element when I inspect an element in chrome. I see 43px there.

Comment: Oopsies...Sorry people. The reason behind discrepancy was that I had zoomed the google.com page to 144%. 30 * 1.44 = 43.2. So, that is why computed style was higher than what the css specified!

Comment: my Chrome computed style reads 30px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I had set zoom scale for google.com to 144%. So, what would have been 30px by default, became 30 * 1.44 = 42px.

Once I set the zoom scale to 100%, the discrepancy vanished.

Comment: +1 I've done that, too -- I often increase the page scaling in the browser to make it easier to read. Works well on SO, but poorly in designs with proportional image placement. It was also the first time my design worked perfectly in IE but "broke" in Chrome :/